# Is 32 bit Ubuntu installation necessary to install 64 bit Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm going to install Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin(x64)  and [this article](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-decide-if-you-should-use-32bit-or-64bit-ubuntu/)  says it requires clean install from 32 bit. Does it mean -- forgive me, I'm Turk and my English is not perfect -- "First install 32 bit and then install 64 bit onto it?"

Answer (score 10):

> By [*"requires clean install from 32-bit"* (under *"64bit Cons"*)](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-decide-if-you-should-use-32bit-or-64bit-ubuntu/) that page is trying to convey exactly the opposite of your assumption. It means that if you start with a 32-bit system, you *cannot* "upgrade" it to be 64-bit. Instead, you *have* to start fresh with a "clean" *64-bit* installation.

You do not need to start with a 32-bit installation to get a 64-bit installation.

In fact, you really can't convert a 32-bit installation into a 64-bit installation. "Cross-grading" is unsupported and all existing methods for attempting it are likely to leave you with a poorly functioning system that contains some 64-bit and some 32-bit components.

**If you want to install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu, just install that.** Having the 32-bit version installed first will only complicate things, as you'd have to remove it or install over it.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**
They are simply stating that you cannot upgrade an existing 32-bit Ubuntu installation to a newer, 64-bit version without first erasing the previous Ubuntu installation.

You may install a fresh copy of the 64-bit version of Ubuntu exactly as you would install the 32-bit version.

Comment: You too SirCharlo.

Answer (score 2):

Simply - No. Just run the installation and install 64 bit version.

One of the cons you are referencing to, *Requires clean install from 32bit*, means that if you want to upgrade from 32 bit version to 64 one, this will not work - you'll need to make a clean install.

Comment: And you too Andrejs.